# Direction of $V_RM$ confusion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, velocity, relative-motion

So ,please read both the questions . They have similar originate questions that I am facing difficult in.

Let us say rain is falling downwards with v = -5j and a man is moving with a velocity of 2i in right direction.

So, from relative motion in 1D. We learnt that whenever we find relative motion like in this case.We keep the reference body at rest.

For example , if I move 2m/s ahead and my friend moves 1m/s ahead.Distance between them is 10m.So , we say that Velocity of me with respect to my friend is 1m/s.Therefore , by keeping my friend at rest.We can say that I only have to 1m/s ahead.

Similarly , during rain man problem.[image]

We found$V_{RM}$ here,

So can we say that by keeping the man at rest , velocity if  rain direction is $V_{RM}$ but intuitively, that is not true.

This is what I am not getting

The question was $V_R$ = 3i-8j form which this problem above originates is this

[image]

Now , I am confused with it that person has to keep the umbrella along with$ V_{RM}$ or V$_R$.

Now , the answer is 3i instead of - 3i (as you can see form diagram ).

So , why is it -3i? We already found $V_{RM}$ , then why to choose answer as Vm.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit misleading to say "keeping the man/body at rest", it's better to say that "in the man's/body's frame".

Anyway I think you get it right, the relative velocity matters.
In 2D you can handle the horizontal and vertical components independently and apply the same rules as in 1D. Just you should consider the signs of the velocities carefully when added. (E.g. if the man has $v_m$ velocity, than in the man's frame, the horizontal component of the rain gets an extra $-v_m$)

Also can you clarify the velocities? What is the velocity of the man, when $v_r=3i-8j$?